# Control Characters and String Manipulation

Tags: string, batch-file

Using the trick posted on [ss64 by Jeb](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1344) to save the backspace control character into a variable - I get strange results when 'overlapping' backspaces.

The example is in a code golfing challenge posted here: [Backhanded^H^H^H^H^H^Hspaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/backhandedhhhhhhspaces/53033#53033) (would appreciate any tips to get this code shorter).

Ungolfed it could look like this:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('"prompt $H&echo on&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set DEL=%%a

set s=%1
echo %s:^H=!DEL!%
```

Basically, it uses Jeb's trick to save backspace as a variable, then uses string manipulation to replace all instances of `^H` in the input string with that variable. Which works correctly for the following example, and similar inputs:

```
C:\>bsp.bat "testing^H^H^H test"
"test test"
```

However when 'overlapping' usage of `^H` occurs, I get the following confusing (to me) output:

```
C:\>bsp.bat "AAA^HB^H^H"
"A"B
```

My question is - with the above example, why am I receiving this output instead of the expected `"A"`?

Comment: I must ask why you want to do this?  You're playing with undocumented legacy console behavior in a language that hasn't seen an update in over a decade, and then coming here to ask about some quirky behavior you found.  The answer is almost certainly lost to history.

Comment: @RyanBemrose Why I want to do it - I'm a big fan of hacky solutions, especially for code golfing, and especially in Batch. "Lost to history" - We'll see, I actually really doubt that the answer to my question is all that obscure. I just don't understand enough about CMD's handling of control characters or string manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why the "expected output" should be "A". See this character-by-character output:

```
bsp.bat "AAA^HB^H^H"
"
"A
"AA
"AAA
"AAA    <- backspace, the cursor is over last "A"
"AAB
"AAB    <- backspace, the cursor is over last "B"
"AAB    <- backspace, the cursor is over second "A"
"A"B
```

The BS character just *moves* the cursor one character back. The "standard behaviour" of BackSpace key (also called "BackSpace echo") is "BackSpace+space+BackSpace".

By the way, this is the method I used to get  BS character:

```
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set BS=%%a
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My mistake. Like I said, a matter of not understanding the control character itself - or the concept of BackSpace echo. I have changed the string manipulation to `%s:^H=!D! !D!%`.

Answer (score 4):

The `"A"B` result is to be expected because the backspace character (0x08) `<BS>` only moves the cursor back without erasing the character.

When you use PROMPT $H, it actually prints `<BS><space><BS>`. The first `<BS>` moves back one, the space overwrites (visually clears) the character, and then the 2nd `<BS>` moves back again to where you want to be.

The default delimiter with FOR /F is `<tab><space>`, so your assignment only preserves the first `<BS>`. Change the delimter to "r" and you get your desired result:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=r" %%a in ('"prompt $H&echo on&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set DEL=%%a

set s=%1
echo %s:^H=!DEL!%
```

Or, preserve the single `<bs>` definition and explicitly overwrite the character yourself:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('"prompt $H&echo on&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set DEL=%%a

set s=%1
echo %s:^H=!DEL! !DEL!%
```

Comment: Good answer. In the interest of saving a few bytes for the code golfing challenge I have gone with my same capturing of the backspace character, and changed the string manipulation to `%s:^H=!D! !D!%`. Thanks.

Comment: I was in the midst of making that same basic edit as your comment came through :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `prompt` to move the cursor back, see here: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php#CursorPositioning

Basically this will move the cursor backwards 3 places:

`prompt $E[3D`